# Javascript error with setting a default value for function

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function:

```
function modifySpinner(currentIcon, selector, spinType = remove)
{
    if (spinType === 'add') {
        // something
    }
}
```

But I am receiving this error in my console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

This wasn't causing issues in firefox? But in chrome its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function modifySpinner(currentIcon, selector, spinType)
{
    var spinType = spinType || "remove" 

    if (spinType === 'add') {
        // something
    }
}
```

So why this works: if the spinType doesn't have a value it equates to `undefined`.  With  `var spinType = spinType || "remove"` you are saying "hey evaulate spinType and if it's false, then use remove."  `undefined` and `null` both evaluate to false in this conditional statement so, it's shorthand for saying if this value is undefined, use this other value instead.

[Truthy and Falsy in Javascript](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this syntax for a default value.

```
function modifySpinner(currentIcon, selector, spinType )
{
  spinType = spinType || "remove";
  if (spinType === 'add') {
      // something
  }
}
```

Like this, if it's `undefined`, `null`, ... The value will be `remove`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have default parameters (it's been introduced in Ecmascript 6), you have to do the check yourself:

```
function modifySpinner(currentIcon, selector, spinType)
{
    spinType = typeof spinType  !== 'undefined' ? spinType : 'remove';
    if (spinType === 'add') {
        // something
    }
}
```